# Newline at end of JSP file breaks Java

Tags: java, jsp, newline

I have a JSP file that consists of two `<%@ include ...` lines and a scriptlet, nothing else.  The file ends with the scriplet closing `%>`, and no new line.  The file compiles and is served by Tomcat as expected.

If I add a new line to the end of the file (more precisely, when Emacs does it automatically after I edit the file), the page produces a 500 error "Unable to compile class" with the specific complaint that the final line (now effectively `%>\n`) is "unreachable code".

I've gone back-and-forth in multiple editors, and I'm certain that the *only* difference between functioning and non-functioning files is the presence of the new line at the end of the file.  I've searched, and I can't find any discussion of this kind of problem.  Why does the closing newline break Java/Tomcat in this instance?

Comment: Could be a conflict between emacs line ending (LF only) and what Tomcat might be expecting (CR + LF).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760290/emacs-change-default-line-ending) might help.

Comment: Please show your JSP file.

Comment: @AndrewS A good suggestion, but I don't think that's it. Among other reasons, if I add a carriage return explicitly to the end of the file before the newline, Java compilation still breaks.