# Emacs encoding of pasted text

Tags: windows, emacs, character-encoding

I'm using (occasionaly) emacs24.3 on windows 8 and I have a problem of encoding when **pasting text**, non ascii characters being replaced by their `\uucode`. My emacs coding default are utf-8

I tried to have a quick look in the apropos help, but nothing matched the keywords i used.

What would be the **variable** to configure, and the value of **system encoding** for a windows os?

Comment: Here are my settings, which I believe includes the clipboard (i.e., selection):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some [digging](http://blog.jonnay.net/archives/820-Emacs-and-UTF-8-Encoding.html), and orientation from [lawlist link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489)

I went for `(set-clipboard-coding-system 'utf-16le-dos)`

Comment: looks like `utf-16le` is sufficient.