# Wrong encoding when pasting into emacs

Tags: emacs, file-encodings

I'm trying to paste accented characters (eg: á, é, í) into Emacs but here's what I get:

[image: accents pasted into emacs]

When I paste into some other editor, like Vim, it works fine. I already tried putting this in my `init.el`

```
(setq utf-translate-cjk-mode nil)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-clipboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

but didn't seem to help. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention, my OS is Arch Linux and the system encoding is also UTF-8.

**EDIT2:** Firstly I thought this was an encoding problem, but I found it's actually related to `evil-mode`. This only happens when I'm using `"+p` of evil

Comment: The only other thing I have is:  `(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)`  I also use: `(add-to-list 'file-coding-system-alist '("\\.tex" . utf-8-unix) )` for each file extension that I normally use.

Comment: Please give some details of how you copy&paste.  E.g. are you running inside a terminal emulator?

Comment: @Stefan I found out it's related to evil mode. Emacs `C-y` pastes normal, the problem seems to be in `"+p` of evil. I'll add this to my question

Comment: What about pasting into X-enabled emacs with the middle mouse button click? It bugs me big time, although pasting with `C-y` is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emacs encoding of pasted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647517/emacs-encoding-of-pasted-text)

Comment: I have this issue only when Simpleclip is on. I need to turn it off then on again whenever my clipboard contains non ascii chars. :(