# Prevent Emacs from adding ^M to end of lines in file

Tags: emacs

On certain occasions, when I save a buffer I have made changes to, it automatically adds ^M to the end of the lines. I find this problematic as it makes reading git diffs a pain. Is there any way to disable Emacs from doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to my setup:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489

Comment: Is there any line not end with `^M`?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the output encoding with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>. You will notice that some encodings end in `-dos`: these will insert `^M` at line ends. Select the encoding that ends in `-unix`, it shouldn't add the characters.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but C-x Return f shows command options beginning with f.

Comment: @user2475612, this is a bit of a strange keybinding. Make sure you're doing Ctrl+X, *then return*, then F. (Don't do F then return.) This should run `set-buffer-file-coding-system`.

Comment: Not sure what you've got customized, but `C-x f` defaults to `set-fill-column`

Comment: @EmacsFodder  `C-x f` is different from `C-x <Enter> f`

Comment: You're quite right @jwernerny, I was blind to the `Return`.