# Emacs Windows org-mode encoding

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, org-mode

I have an org-mode file for todos, and I have renamed the todo bullets to "Att göra" (TODO in swedish). However org-mode (in Windows, see exact version below) think it is "Att gÃ¶ra" (pressing M-S-RET). I can see åäö correct, but "Att göra" is not intepreted as a TODO item. I can also see in the configuration files that it is spelled "Att göra", still org-mode think it is "Att gÃ¶ra".

I have tried to save the configuration files and my org-mode file in UTF-8 (C-x RET f utf-8 RET). I have the following in my Emacs configuration:

```
;; Prefer utf-8
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(keyboard-coding-system (quote utf-8))
 '(selection-coding-system (quote utf-8)))
```

This happens only in Emacs for Windows (I think this is the version number):

> GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)  of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN

It works in Mac, Cygwin (however I have trouble with M-S-RET as the terminal doesn't transfer that sequence right, despite that I have disabled the Alt-Enter shortcut to go fullscreen), Linux etc. It is only in Emacs Windows standalone client.

If you have any idea why this is, I would be very greateful for your suggestions.

Comment: Here is a link to thread containing my setup:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20736147/2112489  In addition to what is there in the link, you may want to add:  `(add-to-list 'file-coding-system-alist '("\\.org" . utf-8-unix) )`  If `utf-8-unix` doesn't work because you are on Windows, then try just `utf-8` -- i.e., replace all of the references in the example.

Comment: Thanks very much for your tips, unfortunately it didn't do any difference. I start to wonder, since you have so many settings for encoding and neither utf-8-unix nor utf-8 work, if it is something internally in org-mode.

Comment: I recently had some issues I'd never had before, and don't understand my solution, but something started working when I added `(modify-coding-system-alist 'file "" 'utf-8-unix)`. I would be curious if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Brady! It seems to work like a charm! As of you I don't know either what "modify-coding-system-alist" means (looked it up in the help but I didn't understand a word of it). I have only tested it on Windows and Cygwin (not Mac and Linux...I will test that tonight). Please, post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to leave this question answered.

Brady told med to add

```
(modify-coding-system-alist 'file "" 'utf-8-unix)
```

to my Emacs file and it works! No idea what it really does.

Comment: A good test file for this fix is the spanish.org flashcard example for org-drill from org-plus-contrib https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill/src/bc740455003b/spanish.org   Accented é and ó  Spanish characters didn't display until I used your fix.